# Helicopter induced velocity

Tags: aerodynamics, helicopter

I found this on one book I am now reading, and I dont uderstand how induced velocity is decreasing whyle climbing? And what is the difference between induced velocity and inflow velocity ?[image]

Comment: I think the confusion here might be due to different frames of reference being used for the induced velocity and inflow velocity. Inflow velocity uses a fixed-body frame (meaning the coordinate system's origin is in the center of gravity of the helicopter), whereas induced velocity is defined within the earth's frame of reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ...I dont uderstand how induced velocity is decreasing whyle climbing?

In the text it states: "The name 'induced' comes from the fact that the rotor forces this velocity into the air." When the helicopter is climbing, there is air flowing into the rotor already, without having to be sucked in and acelerated by the rotor.

> And what is the difference between induced velocity and inflow velocity ?

- Inflow velocity: the average velocity of all the air flowing into the rotor.
- Induced velocity: the difference between average rotor inflow and outflow velocity.

So the term 'induced' refers to the thrust generation of the rotor. Picture below is Figure 2.5 from Principles Of Helicopter Aerodynamics, by J. Gordon Leishman, and illustrates momentum theory of a helicopter in the hover

[image]

The induced velocity $v_i$ can be seen in the pic, and when in the hover the induced velocity is identical to the inflow velocity: the rotor does all the work generating the airflow, creating negative pressure above the rotor.

When the helicopter is in a vertical climb however, air is flowing into the rotor already, and there is less induced velocity:

$$V_{in} = v_i + V_C$$ with:

- $V_{in}$ = inflow velocity
- $v_i$ = induced velocity
- $V_c$ = climb speed.

Comment: I'd use picture 2.17 from the same book instead (axial climbing flight). I'd correct also the definition of induced velocity "*the difference between average rotor inflow and outflow velocity*" with a more correct $V_{\inf} - V_{in}$

Comment: @sophit then please do so, you're free to provide your own answers on this site.

Comment: The other answer to this question is already mine... I've only given a suggestion to improve your good answer, you're free to take it or reject it.

Answer (score 1):

What a confusion!

The correct definitions are:

- *induced velocity* $v_i$ denotes the speed (in m/s for example) of the air when going through the rotor; it normally varies on the rotor disk according to the flying conditions (thrust generated, flown manoeuvre, speed, density, ...). It is called induced since this velocity is induced by the rotor's presence.
- *inflow ratio* $\lambda_i$ is simply the induced velocity adimensionalised via the rotating speed of the rotor $\lambda_i=v_i/ \omega R$. It is the same thing as the induced velocity (and sometimes it is indeed termed *induced inflow velocity*) but, as usual in the aerospace world, an adimensionalised quantity is preferred when making performance comparisons, just like $C_l$, $C_d$, Re, and so on.

That one increases while the other decreases is simply nonsense. The picture is also wrong since in reality the streamlines keep on contracting under the rotor (unless when very  close to the ground but that doesn't seem the case there).

If you want to learn something about helicopter I strongly suggest you the legendary [Helicopter Aerodynamics](https://books.google.com/books/about/Helicopter_Aerodynamics_Volume_I.html?id=rxryAgAAQBAJ&redir_esc=y) by [Raymond W. Prouty](https://vertipedia.vtol.org/biographies/getBiography/biographyID/88). Very easy to read, fluent and almost without equations.

Comment: My pictures are from Cyclic and collective book, by Shawn Coyle. I will try to find that book from Raymond W. Prouty

Comment: are you an aviation engineer, or something like that ? Do you have any other book to recommend ?

Comment: @CiricAleksandar: I'd have other books to recommend but they have more equations then words 

Comment: "That one increases while the other decreases is simply nonsense." - If the inflow velocity ($V_{in}$) increases due to an increase in climb velocity ($V_c$), then induced velocity does indeed decrease, no?  After all, the question was asking about induced velocity ($v_i$) vs inflow velocity ($V_{in}$), not induced inflow ratio ($\lambda_i$).

Comment: @Philip: yep I might've been not that clear. My point is that "inflow" and "induced" are two terms often used interchangeably or even together as in "induced inflow velocity". To makes things even more complicated, "inflow" ratio is the adimensionalised "induced" velocity... I'll try to come up with a clearer answer. Thanks for pointing that out 